# c# DirectShow example shows black screen, but sound is OK

Tags: c#, directshow, h.264, bda

DirectShowLib.DVB-T example "DTVViewer" plays audio, but doesn't play video, I think it's because of H.264 video compressor, which is used in our Digital television and "DTVViewer" is trying to decompress MPEG2.

I want to ask how to form Graph and what filters to use to make "DTVViewer" support H.264?
CurrentGraph.

"MPEG2 DEMULTIPLEXER" pins:

(1)->BDA MPEG2 TRANSPORT INFORMATION FILTER

(2)->DScaler Mpeg2 Video Decoder->Video Renderer

(3)->AUDIO PART...

(5)->MPEG-2 SECTIONS AND TABLES

(ViPin) = AMMediaType(formatType?majorType?subType?)->Filter?->Video Renderer

Thinking, that now i only need help to configure new VideoPin correctly and add some H.264 decoder to it. Can anyone suggest something?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using Geraint Davies' free mpeg4 demux available at http://www.gdcl.co.uk/mpeg4/ instead of mpeg2 demultiplexer

Comment: I'm not able to use the gdcl demux with the DTVViewer. VS don't let me to add a reference to mp4demux.dll and I can't use the regsvr32 to register it. I'm not really familiar with these kind of stuff. What should I do?

Comment: I was able to register it. Now what? :) I can't find a simple tutorial .

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Windows 7, you could look at using the Microsoft decoders. Take a look at the graph at this question:  [best way to build graph for MPEG2 transport stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078713/best-way-to-build-graph-for-mpeg2-transport-stream).

As for what to specify for the video type, I use major type = video, subtype = H264, format type = video info.