# best way to build graph for MPEG2 transport stream

Tags: windows-7, directshow, windows-media-player, mpeg-2, ms-media-foundation

on windows 7 the windows media player supports .ts files very well,
in the sense that windows media player knows how to handle such files without any additional codec packs.

however if I try to use graphedit to "render" a .ts file, it complains it 
doesnt know how to build a graph for it.

what method does windows media player use to demux/decode these files?
is it directshow? windows media foundation? BDA? Microsoft TV Technologies? unified tuning model?

whatever the method they use, is available as an API to be used in my custom application?

Comment: In Windows 7, Windows Media Player uses Media Foundation instead of DirectShow.

Comment: I took your comment seriously, and used the media foundation's TOPOedit application to try and render my .ts file.
it just said that the file's byte format is incompatible ...
so how does mediaplayer do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In DirectShow using only Microsoft filters it can be a bit of a mess.  The Mpeg2 Demultiplexer needs to be manually configured through code using the [IMpeg2Demultiplexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd407128%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface or through the property pages to add output pins for the content streams.  Normally you would need to connect something else to the filter to parse the PSI/PAT information and identify the program ids of the content streams inside the transport stream.  Microsoft provides an [SDK sample](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd377479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to do this in the Windows Platform SDK.

This is assuming that you have a regular mpeg2 transport stream file.  You can use the free apps [MediaInfo](http://mediainfo.sourceforge.net/en) or [TsReader Lite](http://www.tsreader.com/tsreader/index.html) to see exactly what is in your ts file.

There are non-Microsoft filters that make handling transport streams in DirectShow a lot easier.  The combination of the open source filters Haali Media Splitter and Ffdshow will do it without any extra configuration.  Or commercial filter packages from MainConcept, Elecard, LEADTools, etc.

I haven't done much hands-on work with Media Foundation, so I don't have much advice to offer on that front.  Newer versions of Windows Media Player use MF instead of DirectShow.  Some, but not all, new MF functionality is also exposed through DirectShow interfaces.

Comment: good answer, but i'm still left wondering how MS does it in windows media player

Comment: Like I said, they use something through Media Foundation instead of DirectShow.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure of the method used by Windows Media Player.

I've used DirectShow to build a graph. From the source, you can add an MPEG-2 Demultiplexer, create the Audio and Video pins (using the IMpeg2Demultiplexer interface), then hook the Audio pin to the "Microsoft DTV-DVD Audio Decoder" and the Video pin to the "Microsoft DTV-DVD Video Decoder". You can then feed the outputs into an audio and a video renderer.

For example, here is part of a graph I have used:
[image: Render Graph]

David

Comment: what application did you use for showing the graph? it doesn't look like graphedit or like radscorpion's graphstudio?
does it support the IMpeg2Demultiplexer interface or do you have to use this interface in a custom application?

Comment: This is from [GraphEditPlus](http://www.infognition.com/GraphEditPlus/). It doesn't directly support IMpeg2Demultiplexer, but you can open the properties box on the filter and set the items through the property dialog. GraphEditPlus can also generate C# or C++ code from a graph, but you would have to add the code to use the IMpeg2Demultiplexer manually, since it doesn't know about it.